# RESTful controller routes with wildcards

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I am trying to create a CMS and I want to route to a RESTful controller that will take the id of a post, retrieve that post and place it in a form for editing. My route for this is:

```
Route::get('dashboard/posts/edit/(:any)', array(
    'as' => 'edit_post',
    'uses' => 'posts@edit'));
```

If I try to go to this route I get a 404.

If I replace (:any) with a specific id it routes correctly. 
Is there some sort of limitation on using wildcards with restful controllers, or have I exceeded a limit on the number of segments a route can have?

By the way I am using laravel 3.

Comment: Have you tried using `(:num)`, or a stanard expression, such as `(\d+)`?

Comment: @MikeAnthony Thanks for the response. I just tried both of those and I am still getting the 404.

Comment: There shouldn't be any such limitations. I do indeed find this quite weird. Are any of your other wildcard routes not working? And, are you using the latest build of Laravel 3?

Comment: PS, you might find that Laravel 4 Resource Controllers will better suit your needs: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: I am using the latest build of 3. I will try switching over to Laravel 4.